# Volley timeout error attempting to POST to localhost

Tags: android, post, request-queueing

I've battling a volley timeout error when attempting to post a registration form to a localhost (WAMP) for testing purposes. I've been looking at the code for sometime and cannot seem to find the issue. Timeout errors from what I understand are generally due to connection issues. I don't seem to be getting any errors via logcat, and the URL to my localhost php file seem to be correct.

I hope it's something small. In my db_function.php file, I did `(include/connectiondb.php)` but not sure if its correct. I originally had `(connectiondb.php)` but still no go.

All my code is below.

database details

```
CREATE TABLE jobseekerusers (
jobSeekerId int,
jobSeekerFirstName VARCHAR,
jobSeekerLastName VARCHAR,
jobSeekerEmaiLAddress VARCHAR,
jobSeekerPasswordVARCHAR,
);
```

connectdb.php

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'Discover');

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);


?>
```

db_function.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
$jobFirstName = $_POST['jobFirstName'];
$jobLastName = $_POST['jobLastName'];
$jobEmailAddress = $_POST['jobEmailAddress'];
$jobPassword = $_POST['jobPassword'];

require_once('include/connectdb.php');

$sql = "INSERT INTO jobseekerusers(jobSeekerFirstName, jobSeekerLastName, 
jobSeekerEmailAddress, jobSeekerPassword)
values ('$jobFirstName', '$jobLastName', '$jobEmailAddress', 
'$jobPassword')";
if(mysql_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo "Success";
}
else
{
    echo "Fail";
}

}
else
{
echo "Something Failed";
}
?>
```

job_seeker_sign_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_gradient_orange"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_full_name"
            android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:id="@+id/cardView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="6"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/signUp"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/jobFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="#FAFAFA"
                    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/rate"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/employerFirstName"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/jobLastName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#FAFAFA"
                    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/employer_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/employerLastName"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/jobEmailAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="#FAFAFA"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/email_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/employerEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/jobPassword"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#FAFAFA"
                    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/password_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/employerPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/jobSubmit"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_gradient_orange"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/jobHaveAccount"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#999"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/haveAccount"/>
    </LinearLayout>


   </RelativeLayout>


 </ScrollView>
```

jobSeekerPage.java

```
package com.example.dennis.discover;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JobSeekerSignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {
private TextView jobHaveAccount;
private TextView jobFirstName;
private TextView jobLastName;
private TextView jobEmailAddress;
private TextView jobPassword;
private Button jobSubmit;
String URL = "http://192.168.0.9/Discover/db_functions.php";
public static final String FIRSTNAME = "jobSeekerFirstName";
public static final String LASTNAME = "jobSeekerLastName";
public static final String EMAILADDRESSID = "jobSeekerEmailAddress";
public static final String PASSWORD = "jobSeekerPassword";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_seeker_sign_up);

    jobHaveAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobHaveAccount);
    jobFirstName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobFirstName);
    jobLastName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobLastName);
    jobEmailAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobEmailAddress);
    jobPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobPassword);
    jobSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.jobSubmit);
    jobSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);



    jobHaveAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent jobSeekerSignIn = new Intent(JobSeekerSignUp.this, 
 JobSeekerLogIn.class);
            startActivity(jobSeekerSignIn);
        }
    });

  }

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    final String firstName = jobFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String lastName = jobLastName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String emailAddress = jobEmailAddress.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = jobPassword.getText().toString().trim();

 //Initiate request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
 //get String Response using URL (variable defined above - currently WAMP)
    StringRequest stringrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
 URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(JobSeekerSignUp.this, response, 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(JobSeekerSignUp.this, error.toString(), 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(FIRSTNAME, firstName);
            params.put(LASTNAME, lastName);
            params.put(EMAILADDRESSID, emailAddress);
            params.put(PASSWORD, password);


            return super.getParams();
        }
    };

    // Adding the request to the request queue
    requestQueue.add(stringrequest);

 }


}
```

Comment: `Volley timeout error attempting to POST to localhost`. Volley code runs on an Android device. Every device is its own localhost. So are you telling that you post to a server on your Android device?

Comment: add this it may be help you
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);

Comment: @greenapps - Yes, i'm trying to POST to a WAMP server mainly for testing.

Comment: @Sanjay- Still doesn't work sorry.

Comment: The information isn't posting to the WAMP server either. I'm not getting any errors other then timeout Volley error and logcat seems to be fine.

Comment: `Yes, i'm trying to POST to a WAMP server mainly for testing.`. Your remark does not make sense. Please reread my comment and then react to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your firewall if on windows, or disabling Avast shields. It worked for me.